# How to constrain the type of generic parameter to a Typescript function to be an enum

Tags: generics, typescript, enums

Is it possible to constrain the type of an input parameter to a generic Typescript function to be a Typescript enum?

In other words, I want to enforce that T in the function below is a non-constant Typescript enum
    `Foo<T>() { /* */ }`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to limit T to just enums.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can constrain the type to a specific enum.

```
function foo<T extends MyEnum>(param: T) {    
}
```

However, you cannot constrain it to be any enum (see [specs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types)).

> In addition to generic interfaces, we can also create generic classes. Note that it is not possible to create generic enums and namespaces.

Comment: This seems to only constrain to a number, not the enum.  So you could call it with `foo(7);`.  See [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FOO%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo%3CT%20extends%20MyEnum%3E(param%3A%20T)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(MyEnum.FOO)%3B%0D%0Afoo(7)%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail%2C%207%20is%20not%20a%20MyEnum%0D%0A)