# How to emulate "T extends enum" generic constraint?

Tags: typescript, enums

[I'm already aware that TypeScript does not allow enums as constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033142/how-to-constrain-the-type-of-generic-parameter-to-a-typescript-function-to-be-an), but is there a way - even a hacky one - to get similar behaviour?

```
export enum StandardSortOrder {
    Default,
    Most,
    Least
}

export enum AlternativeOrder {
    Default,
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}

export interface IThingThatUsesASortOrder<T extends enum> { // doesn't compile
    sortOrder: T;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such constraint in typescript. The best you can do is use the base type of the enum, which in this case is `number` (if you need to use string enums then you would use `string` or `string | number` if you want to allow both)

```
export enum StandardSortOrder {
    Default,
    Most,
    Least
}

export enum AlternativeOrder {
    Default,
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}

export interface IThingThatUsesASortOrder<T extends number> { 
    sortOrder: T;
}

let a: IThingThatUsesASortOrder<StandardSortOrder>
let a2: IThingThatUsesASortOrder<AlternativeOrder>
```

Comment: I was afraid of this... it seems like a massive omission.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611 Here's the related issue on Github